# Suppose $n$ is an even positive integer and $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$. Prove that either every element of $H$ is...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $n$ is an even positive integer and $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$. Prove that either every element of $H$ is even or exactly half of its elements are even. (Gallian, *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*, Exercise 24, Chapter 3.)

Comment: What have you thought of/tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to start. If you can suggest something about how to deal with the question then it will be really helpful

Comment: You could start by figuring out what the possible subgroups of $\mathbb Z/n \mathbb Z$ are.

Comment: Show that any such $H$ is cyclic. Then see what happens when the generator is odd versus even.

Comment: It's not Z/nZ. It is Zn = [0,1,....,n-1]

Comment: @ShivaniGoel Which is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try as suggested by Arthur.

Comment: elements of $H$ are cosets, so saying they are even or odd does not make sense. You should rather say coset representatives of elements of $H$ are even.

Comment: My question is for Zn but someone edited it and write Z / nZ

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth: $H$ is a group, and the order of elements in it are perfectly well-defined.

Comment: What is the point of closing this old question that already has three answers, especially after [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793835/suppose-n-is-even-positive-integer-and-h-is-a-subgroup-of-mathbb-z-n?lq=1) was (rightly) closed as a duplicate of this one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This proof uses very elementary group theory (as per [Gathdi's request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793835/suppose-n-is-even-positive-integer-and-h-is-a-subgroup-of-mathbb-z-n)) — it does not use homomorphisms or cosets, and it does not even assume the well-known result that every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic (a special case of it is proved here itself).

$\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z = \{0, 1, \ldots, n - 1\}$.

Let $H$ be any subgroup of $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$. If all elements of $H$ are even, we have the desired result. Otherwise, if at least one element of $H$ is odd, let $k$ be the least such odd element. Then we can prove that

1. $H = \langle k \rangle$, the cyclic subgroup generated by $k$, and
2. $H$ has even order, and half the elements of $H$ are even.

To prove the first statement, let $m$ be any element of $H$. Then using the division algorithm,
\begin{equation*}
m = qk + r, \quad 0 \le r < k
\end{equation*}
for some integers $q$ and $r$. Now, $r < k$ is an element of $H$ (since $r = m - qk$, $m, k \in H$), so it cannot be odd, due to our assumption on $k$. But if $r$ is even, then $k - r > 0$ is an odd element of $H$, which is possible only if $k - r \ge k$, so in fact, $k - r = k$ (since $r \ge 0$). Thus, $r = 0$, and $m = qk$, which proves that $H = \langle k \rangle$.

Now, the order of $H$ is the order of the element $k$, which is the smallest positive integer $s$ such that $sk = ln$, for some integer $l$ (as $n$ is the order of the group $G$). But given that $n$ is even, and $k$ is odd, it must be that $s$ is even. Thus, $H$ has even order, and since $H = \{0, k, 2k, 3k, \ldots, (s - 1)k \}$, exactly half of the elements of $H$, namely $0, 2k, 4k, \ldots, (s - 2)k$, are even.

Comment: This is a special case of a beautiful result that states that if $N$ is any index $2$ subgroup of a group $G$, then every subgroup $H$ of $G$ is either completely contained in $N$ ($H \le N$), or exactly half inside and half outside $H$ ($|H : (N \cup H)| = 2$). Here, the subgroup of even elements of $\mathbb Z_n$, namely $2 \mathbb Z_n$, is an index $2$ subgroup, and therefore, any subgroup $H$ is either contained in it (consists only of even elements), or is exactly half inside it (half of all its elements are even).

Comment: In the last line, $(s-1)k$ is odd, because $s$ is even and therefore $s - 1$ is odd.

Comment: @Junglemath Fixed. Thank you!

Comment: @M.Vinay  here  |H:(N∪H)|=2 we have union or intersection?

Comment: @MeetPatel Oops, it should $N \cap H$. Typoed `\cap` as `\cup`, I guess. Of course, $N \cup H$ is not a subgroup of $H$ (and most likely not a subgroup of even $G$), so $|H : (N \cup H)|$ is meaningless. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try this: let $G=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}_n$. Then consider a subgroup $H$ of $G$. Because $G$ is cyclic, $H$ is cyclic. Suppose $H$ does not consist of all even elements. Then there exists an odd element in $H$. However, if $H$ is generated by an even element, then all elements in $H$ will be even. Therefore $H$ is generated by an odd element.

Now let's try to set up a bijection between even and odd elements of $H$. Let $H=\langle a\rangle$ where $a$ is odd. Then (in additive notation) $ca$ is even if $c$ is even, and odd if $c$ is odd.

Let $\phi(ca)=da$ where $d\equiv (c+1)\pmod a$, $0\leq d\lt |a|$. This clearly maps between even and odd components. You can check that this is a bijection fairly easily.

There could be a much easier way to do this, but this is what I came up with.

Comment: The bijection you have defined is quite new to me. Otherwise the method suggested by you is really good.

Comment: A bijection means that the mapping $\phi$ is both injective (1-1) and surjective (onto). You can look up those definitions if you need to, but showing a bijection exists is a very common way to show two sets have equal size.

Comment: I know what is a bijection. I was trying to say the mapping u have defined is new to me.

Comment: There is no need to assume that $H$ is cyclic. In the non-trivial case it's enough to suppose that $a\in H$ is odd.

Answer (score 3):

Since $n$ is even, one has $n\mathbf Z\subseteq 2\mathbf Z$ and, consequently, a morphism of quotient groups 
$$
f\colon \mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z\rightarrow \mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z.
$$
Explicitly, $f$ maps de class of $m$ mod $n$ to the class of $m$ mod $2$, for any integer $m$. Of course, $f$ is surjective, and its kernel is the subgroup $2\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ of ''even'' elements of $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$.

Now, if $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ then either $H$ is contained in the kernel of $f$, or it is not. In the former case, all elements of $H$ are even. In the latter case, the restriction of $f$ to $H$ is a surjective morphism $g$ from $H$ into $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$. It follows that the kernel $\ker(g)$ of $g$ is a subgroup of $H$ of index $2$. In particular, $\ker(g)$ and its complement $H\setminus\ker(g)$ have the same number of elements since both are classes of the subgroup $\ker(g)$ of $H$. In particular, they have the same number of elements. The elements of $\ker(g)$ are the ''even'' elements of $H$, the elements of $H\setminus\ker(g)$ are the ''odd'' elements of $H$.