# Suppose n is even positive integer and $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $n$ is even positive integer and $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_n$. Prove that either every member of $H$ is even or exactly half of members of $H$ are even.

Same question have been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336489/suppose-n-is-an-even-positive-integer-and-h-is-a-subgroup-of-mathbb-z-n-m), but I ask it again because I do not understand answers because of concepts like isomorphism and cosets etc. Need a simple answer.

Thanks

Comment: $H$ will have the form $\{0,d,2d,...,(n/d-1)d\}$ for some divisor $d | n.$ The two cases are whether $d$ is even or odd.

Comment: If you don't like the answers given, the correct procedure is to make further comments etc there, not to ask the question again.

Comment: Gathdi, I've [answered it](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1794018/152030) without using any "advanced" stuff. It can be made shorter and simpler if you first separately prove that [every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6998/how-to-show-every-subgroup-of-a-cyclic-group-is-cyclic) — the proof is very similar to a major part of the proof in my answer.